# mod_rewrite regex sub domain plus folders

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have looked everywhere for this solution but have not seen a good enough match that I can reconfigure on my server.

I want  school.mysite.com/math/ to map to mysite.com/index.php?inst=school&sub=math

I can do either half but not both together.

IE I can get mysite.com/math/ to mysite.com/index.php?sub=math with :

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_]+)/?$ index.php?sub=$1 [L]
```

and I can get school.mysite.com to mysite.com/index.php?inst=school with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-zA-Z_]+).mysite.com/?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?inst=%1
```

but I cannot for the life of my get the two to work together, I tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-zA-Z_]+).mysite.com/([a-zA-Z_]+)/?
RewriteRule ^(.*$) index.php?inst=$1&sub=$2 [L]
```

and a whole bunch of other variants and I either get a 404 error (like  get for the regex above) or that it only catches the first variable only.

What am I missing?

thanks

zen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z_]+)\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/?$ index.php?inst=%1&sub=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: 1 week of struggling solved in 5 minutes, not sure if I want to weep or laugh. Thanks anubhava you are a star

Comment: why is there nothing after the .com$ in the condition yet in the rule it is only the bit afterwards that is referenced?... it works perfectly I just dont understand it

Comment: `HTTP_HOST` only matches hostname not the URL. URI is matched in `RewriteRule` in this rule.

Comment: Thanks again anubhava, I'm realising that a week of head scratching is only the start but I'm getting there